# SQL - Select top item from a grouping of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of numbers attached to two separate columns, and I want to just return the first "match" of the two columns to get that data. I got close with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) answer, but it only works with one field. I need it to work with a combination of fields. About ten second before I was ready to post.

Here's an example table "Item":

```
Item    Color     Area
Boat    Red       1
Boat    Red       2
Boat    Blue      4
Boat    Blue      5
Car     Red       3
Car     Red       4
Car     Blue      10
Car     Blue      31
```

And the result set returned should be:

```
Item    Color     Area
Boat    Red       1
Boat    Blue      4
Car     Red       3
Car     Blue      10
```

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler way to do this:

```
select Item,
    Color,
    min(Area) as Area
from Item
group by Item
    Color
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `MIN` function with a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Item, Color, MIN(area) AS Area
FROM Item
GROUP BY Item, Color
```

Output:

```
Item    Color   Area
Boat    Blue    4
Boat    Red     1
Car     Blue    10
Car     Red     3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46a154/1/0

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no "first" of anything without a column specifying the ordering.

For your example results, the simplest query is:

```
select item, color, min(area) as area
from item i
group by item, color;
```

Answer (score 0):

About ten seconds before I was ready to post the question, I realized the answer:

```
WITH summary AS (
SELECT i.item + ':' + i.color,             
       a.area, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.item + ':' + i.color, 
                             ORDER BY i.item + ':' + i.color DESC) AS rk
  FROM Item i
  group by (i.item + ':' + i.color, i.Area)
```

SELECT s.*
  FROM summary s
 WHERE s.rk = 1

It's as simple as combining the two composite key fields into one field and grouping based on that. This might be a bit hackish so if anyone wants to suggest a better option I'm all for it.